# How to set metadata and send text (.txt) file as attachment without storing on the server in laravel?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, email-attachments

I am working on a module to send chats messages to user email (aka **email transcript**) using laravel 5.6.
I need to save all the chat messages to a txt file and send that file as attachment to user's email address.

I do not want to save the txt file to my server as many people would be using that application and it will increase the storage usage of the server i.e I need to generate the txt file in memory.

I am able to populate the chats in plain email without attachment but this is not the solution if the chat messages increase, email would be too lengthy and seems not professional to me.

This I have tried so far:
**EmailTranscriptController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Trade;
use App\Models\ChatMessage;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\EmailTradeChatMessages;
use Validator;

class EmailTranscriptController extends Controller
{
    public function emailTradeTranscript($tradeId)
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
        $trade = Trade::findClosedTradeByIdByUserId($tradeId, $userId);
        if (is_null($trade)) {
            return response()->api(false, 'Trade not available', null);
        }

        $tradeStartTime = $trade->created_at;
        $tradeCloseTime = $trade->updated_at;


        $tradeChats = ChatMessage::getAllChatByTradeId($tradeId);



        Mail::to($userEmail)->queue(new EmailTradeChatMessages(
            $tradeChats,
            $tradeStartTime,
            $tradeCloseTime
        ));

        return response()->api(true, 'Email Sent Successfully', null);

    }
}
```

**EmailTradeChatMessages.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailTradeChatMessages extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $chats;
    protected $tradeStartTime;
    protected $tradeCloseTime;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($chats, $tradeStartTime, $tradeCloseTime)
    {
        $this->chats = $chats;
        $this->tradeStartTime = $tradeStartTime;
        $this->tradeCloseTime = $tradeCloseTime;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.trade_chat_transcript')->with([
            'chats' => $this->chats,
            'tradeStartTime' => $this->tradeStartTime,
            'tradeCloseTime' => $this->tradeCloseTime,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**trade_chat_transcript.blade.php (dummy)**

```
@component('mail::message')
    #Trade Started at: {{$tradeStartTime}}

    @php
        $count=0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($chats as $chat)
        {{++$count}}
    @endforeach

    #Trade Closed at: {{$tradeCloseTime}}
    Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Kindly help me getting the solution, I would also like to get other approaches to solution,if any.

**Update**

I found the solution for not storing the file on server itself and attach it using attachData() method, as follows:

```
public function build()
    {
        $email= $this->markdown('emails.trade_chat_transcript')->with([
            'tradeId' => $this->tradeId,
            'filename' => $this->filename,
            'tradeStartTime' => $this->tradeStartTime,
            'tradeCloseTime' => $this->tradeCloseTime,
        ])
        ->attachData($this->message,$this->filename,[
            'mime'=>'text/plain'
            ]);


        return $email;
    }
```

Now I need to set metadata of the file to be attached in email eg. Author etc.

Comment: However you need to create file and after sending you can just delete it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637495/how-to-unlink-files-after-they-have-been-attached-and-sent-when-using-mailqu) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the file on the server. That being said you can delete it directly after. There is a method for that:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: I have found the solution of attaching file without storing on the server, see the updated question. Now I need to set metadata for the file.